# Google Translate: Change the layout option

Tags: css, layout, google-translate

I can't find the API library to know what are the variable options for my code below.  I wan to be able to change the layout.  Can anyone help?  Code below.

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                    pageLanguage: 'en',
                    includedLanguages: 'en,es',
                    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
                  }, 'google_translate_element');
                }
                </script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```